# password validation through javascript

Tags: javascript

### fields in form ,password  , repeat_password

```
            <?php echo  form_open('logincontroller/register',array('onsubmit'=>'return validate_registeration()'));?>
function validate_registeration(){

    var  error_flag = 0;

    var  password = $("#password").val();
    var repeat_password = $("#repeat_password").val();

    if(password == ''){
      $("#password").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1; 
    }
    if(password.length <6 && password !== ''){
      $("#password").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1;
      $("#msgBox").text("password must be atleast six character"); 
    }

    if(repeat_password == ''){
      $("#repeat_password").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1; 
    }

    if(password !==repeat_password){
      $("#repeat_password").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1; 
      $("#msgBox").text("Password does'nt match");
    }

  if(repeat_password !== password){
    $("#repeat_password").addClass('error');
    error_flag = 1; 
    $("#msgBox").text("Password does'nt match");
  }

    if(error_flag == 1){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }

  }
```

this is code it don't show me message on password length less than six and dos'nt show password matching message if password dose not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(password.length <6 && password != '')
{
  $("#password").addClass('error');
  error_flag = 1;
  $("#msgBox").text("password must be atleast six character"); 
}

if(password !=repeat_password)
{
  $("#repeat_password").addClass('error');
  error_flag = 1; 
  $("#msgBox").text("Password does'nt match");
}
```

Comment: Thanx Brother for your Valuable help.

Comment: thanx alot this valuable help.